# Sorting Problem with SQLite 3 on Discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

So i tried to make a Levelling system, it works, but the leaderboard does not work properly, It sorting the SQLite content randomly although I already put `ORDER BY lvl also` I tried with `ORDER BY txp` (txp was the total xp), This is the code that I write

```
    @commands.command()
    async def top10(self, ctx):
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id, lvl, txp from levels WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} ORDER BY txp DESC LIMIT 5 ")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboards", colour=discord.Colour(0x6790a7))
        for i, x in enumerate(result, 1):
            embed.add_field(name=f"#{i}", value=f"<@{str(x[0])}> on Level {str(x[1])} with {str(x[2])} Total XP", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        print(result)
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

This is the result

````
[('560578285747306538', '5', '830'), ('441240050861211648', '8', '548'), ('321191503487827970', '4', '548'), ('457159518254792714', '0', '4'), ('448779471810461706', '1', '36')]``` when I print the db
````

And this is the leaderboard looks like
[Leaderboards looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIzx0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the data type of `txp` is `TEXT` so the result is sorted alphabetically.
You must convert it to an integer:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id, lvl, txp from levels WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} ORDER BY txp + 0 DESC LIMIT 5")
```

`txp + 0` implicitly converts `txp` to an integer.

Comment: What if i change the column type to Integer rather than converting it, will it works?

Comment: Yes it will work. But it is not that simple in SQLite if you want to keep the existing data. SQLite does not support alteration of the data type of a column. If you don't care about the existing data delete the table and recreate it.